# Javascript Table won't move

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'd just like to say I am having a problem with moving a table across the page like I would with an image. However it is being problematic. I already know how to move a image in a circle using coordinates or using an equation. I tried applying the co-ordinates way on this, however, even though the table displays and hides properly, the table won't move at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 78px;
            height: 63px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 55px;
            height: 54px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="width: 235px">
    <script>
function moveTable() {
        if (playing == false) {
            myTimer = window.setTimeout(move, 25);
            playing = true;
        }
    }

    leftCoor = new Array(10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130, 110, 90, 70, 50, 30);
    var myTimer;
    var playing = false;
    var index = 0; //was undefined

    function move() {
        //if (playing == false) {
        var tplayer = document.getElementById("tblFormat");
        tplayer.style.visibility = "visible";
        tplayer.style.left = leftCoor[index] + "px";
        index++;

        if (index > 11) index = 0;
        //myTimer = window.setTimeout(move, 100); //corrected
        //playing = false;
        //}

    }

    function CloseTable() {
        var tplayer = document.getElementById("tblFormat");
        tplayer.style.visibility = "hidden";
        tplayer.style.left = "10px";
        window.clearTimeout(myTimer);
        playing = false;

    }

    </script>
    <table class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #FF0000; border: thick inset #0000FF; visibility: hidden; left: 10px;" id="tblFormat">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right">
                <img id="imgClose" alt="" class="auto-style2" src="images/emyller_close_button.png" onclick="CloseTable()" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello World,<br />
                Please hit the close button to close this table.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        <img id="imgOpen" alt="" class="auto-style3" src="images/start-button.png" onmouseover="move()" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

All help is appreciated!

**UPDATED CODE**

Updated code due to ideas from answers.
Still have the same problem, still won't move.

**UPDATED CODE and EDIT #2**

Okay, so it sorta moves, however not in the way I would like it to. I want it to be continuous and only activate on one mouse-over (if that makes sense). Right now, I have to do multiple mouse-overs to make it move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>...</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <script>
        leftCoor = new Array(10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130, 110, 90, 70, 50, 30);
        var myTimer;
        //var playing = false;
        var index = 0;

        function move() {
            //if (playing == false) {
                var tplayer = document.getElementById("tblFormat");
                tplayer.style.visibility = "visible";
                tplayer.style.left = leftCoor[index] + "px";
                index++;

                if (index > 11) index = 0;
                myTimer = window.setTimeout(move, 100); //corrected
                playing = true;
            //}

        }

        function CloseTable() {
            var tplayer = document.getElementById("tblFormat");
            tplayer.style.visibility = "hidden";
            tplayer.style.left = "10px";
            window.clearTimeout(myTimer);
            //playing = false;

        }
   </script>
   <div id="divTable" style="left:10px">
   <table id="tblFormat" style="position:relative"> <!-- position:relative -->
      <tr>
         <td><img id="imgClose" onclick="CloseTable()" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   <img id="imgOpen" onMouseOver="move()" />
 </body>
</html>
```

I rip off some of the code to focus on the staffs that form my answer ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, the table still doesn't move, however I will agree and say those are some very good fixes you have spotted.

Comment: Strange, it move just fine (in my quick test in IE8)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the table linearly, you can use CSS3 tansform properties and not necessarily javascript to accomplish that.

e-g:

```
 #tblFormat:hover{transform:translateX(250px);}
```

Will move your element with id tblFormat in X axis to a distance of 250px on hover.

Comment: Okay, but is it possible to do it strictly through javascript?

Comment: off course, you could change the left value of the element if it has a position specified, but its better to use CSS actually.

Comment: I'd agree with the CSS, however I need to learn how to use Javascript in all aspects due to why I was asking if it was capable of doing it in Java only. In respect to your question, by specified, do you mean - <table class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #FF0000; border: thick inset #0000FF; visibility: hidden; left: 10px;" id="tblFormat">?

Comment: no you need to remove visibility hidden property. there is no point in moving an element if it is invisible.

Comment: visibility helped none, besides I have it set so it becomes visible before executing the 'movement'.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you have the if (playing == false) statement. So after the first time you hovered on the start button, the value of playing is changed to true. Then the code inside if (playing == false) will never get a chance to run.

Comment: Just tried commenting all playing related statements out, thinking that was a good possibility and the table still doesn't move.

Comment: That is because the initial visibility of the table is set to hidden I guess.

Comment: visibility helped none, besides I have it set so it becomes visible before executing the 'movement'.

Comment: The issue of not moving automatically is because you commented this line out: myTimer = window.setTimeout(move, 200);

Answer (score 0):

Your table with class `auto-style1` needs to have `position: relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` to respect the `left` property. This is the root cause; other issues may be present that prevent the table from moving exactly how you want.

Comment: Okay, that sorta worked... It moves if I mouse-over repeatedly... I'll update code.